# Sphinx autodoc if Python method moved to Rust PyO3

Tags: python, rust, documentation, python-sphinx, pyo3

If I have a **Python** module and a method:

```py
# mymod.py
def func(x):
    """
    Return a value.
    """
    return x
```

And a **Sphinx** autodocument command in an rst file:

```
API Ref
-------

.. automodapi:: project.mymod
```

This will generate relevant pages and cross-referencable links for `:meth:'project.mymod.func'`. **All is well and good!**

**However**, If I now create a Rust extension for my Python package and move this function to Rust  and build the extension with PyO3 I can maintain code backwards compatibility by importing the rust function to the Python module as an overload:

```rust
// mymod.rs
#[pymethod]
fn func(x: T) -> PyResult<T> {
    Ok(x)
}
```

```py
# mymod.py
from mymodrs import func
```

**Sphinx** will now no longer auto detect this `func` method, with no cross-referencable link. **Can I add something to maintain the Sphinx operability? I don't mind if it is manual.**

Answer (score 1):

One way I have found so far of getting this to work with *almost* the same formatting and section consistency is to do something like:

**Current Version**

---

```
# mymod.py
def func(x):
    """
    Return a value

    Parameters
    ----------
    x: float
        The value

    Returns
    -------
    float
    """
    return x
```

```
# index.rst
Methods
-------

.. automodapi:: project.mymod
```

---

**New Rust Version**

```
# mymod.py
from mymodrs import func

func.__doc__ = "Return a value"  # Needed for the description in autosummary
```

Create an explicit documentation file for the Rust method.

```
# api_manual/mymod.func.rst
func
----

.. currentmodule:: mymod

.. py:method:: func(x)

   Return a value

   :param x: The value
   :param type: float

   :rtype: float
```

Link to it in the original automod file.

```
# index.rst
Methods
-------

.. autosummary::
   mymod.func

.. toctree::
   :titlesonly:
   :maxdepth: 0
   :hidden:

   api_manual/mymod.func.rst
```